# Height of the div is not resizing according to the content inside

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My div of class .list-holder in the header is not resizing according to the content in the div. If I increase the padding of list items, the content is overflowing outside the div.
I have imported bootstrap CDN

```css
.list-holder {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    margin: 0px 40px;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.list-holder > ul > li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.list-holder > ul > li > a{
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list-holder > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="branding">
        <h1>Blogging</h1>
        <div class="search-btn">
            <button >Get started</button>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Google Search ">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="view-users">
        <div style="display: flex">
            <div class="views">Total Views: 0</div>
            <div class="users">Total Users: 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="list-holder">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Nation</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Sports</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Politics</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Entertainment</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Search</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

also :

Plz anyone say what's my mistake......!

Comment: Please add Bootstrap.css CDN :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` elements should have `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline` in order to trigger height modifications in the parent element.

If you want to use bootstrap, though, you could do something like this to achieve what you wanted (expand the snippet to see the centered menu items):

```css
nav.navbar-dark.bg-dark {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)!important;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
  }
  nav .form-inline {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <h1 class="navbar-brand">Blogging</h1>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nation</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sports</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Politics</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search">
          <button class="btn btn-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Get Started</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row pt-4">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="views card text-center"><h4>Total Views: 0</h4></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="users card text-center"><h4>Total Users: 0</h4></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list-holder {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    margin: 0px 40px;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.list-holder > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.list-holder > ul > li > a{
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list-holder > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="branding">
        <h1>Blogging</h1>
        <div class="search-btn">
            <button >Get started</button>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Google Search ">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="view-users">
        <div style="display: flex">
            <div class="views">Total Views: 0</div>
            <div class="users">Total Users: 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="list-holder">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Nation</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Sports</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Politics</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Entertainment</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Search</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can use `display: inline-block` to **.list-holder > ul > li** instead of `display: inline`